# Ember.js 2.9 simple nested routes error on full page reload

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, ember-router

I am a beginner to Ember.js so I took the Codeschool course 'Try Ember'. So following this course I actually get an error.

My `router.js` file looks like this:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import config from './config/environment';

const Router = Ember.Router.extend({
  location: config.locationType,
  rootURL: config.rootURL
});

Router.map(function() {
  this.route('orders', function(){
    this.route('order', {path: '/:order_id'});
  });

});

export default Router;
```

Now as far as I understand from the tutorial I have two routes `orders.js` and `order.js` with templates `templates/orders.hbs` and `templates/orders/order.hbs` respectively.

`orders.js` file:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model(){
    return [
      { id: '1', name: 'Vlatko'},
      { id: '2', name: 'Mila'}
    ];
  }
});
```

`order.js` file:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model(params){
    return [
      { id: '1', name: 'Vlatko'},
      { id: '2', name: 'Mila'}
    ].findBy('id', params.order_id);
  }
});
```

`templates/orders.hbs` file:

```
<h2>Hello from orders</h2>

{{#each model as |order|}}
  <p>
    {{#link-to 'orders.order' order}}
      Order {{order.id}}
    {{/link-to}}
  </p>
{{/each}}

{{outlet}}
```

`templates/orders/order.hbs` file:

```
<p>Order {{model.id}} for {{model.name}}</p>
```

So everything is pretty simple and works well, but when I try to do a full page reload(enter directly on the page) `/orders/1` it raises two errors

`Error while processing route: orders.order No model was found for 'order' Error: No model was found for 'order'`

and

`Error: No model was found for 'order'`

Now, I've searched a lot on the web and I can't find the same error.

An additional hint: This only happens when I use nested routes. If for instance I have something like this in my `router.js`:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import config from './config/environment';

const Router = Ember.Router.extend({
  location: config.locationType,
  rootURL: config.rootURL
});

Router.map(function() {
  this.route('orders');
  this.route('order', {path: '/orders/:order_id'});
});

export default Router;
```

I get no error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `order.js` file should be `orders/order.js`. Your problem is that ember doesn't find your route so you get the default route. The default model hook with a dynamic segment `order_id` will basically do `store.findRecord('order', theId)`, and so you get the error that the model `order` is not defined because you don't use `ember-data`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Pure logic.